# Devise flash messages not working with Turbo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

I'm running Rails 6.1.4.4 with Devise 4.8.1 and configured my setup to use importmaps and hotwire-rails. When logging in through Devise I no longer get a flash message.

I do get flash messages on other parts of the system.

In the devise controller I can see the flash message being created, but nothing appears in the browser.

```
  def set_flash_message(key, kind, options = {})
    message = find_message(kind, options)
    if options[:now]
      flash.now[key] = message if message.present?
    else
      flash[key] = message if message.present?
    end
  end
```

I do have the following in my application.html.erb layout

```
<div id="notice" class="alert alert-info">
  <%= notice %>
</div>
```

In my controllers I have flash messages working like so;

```
  def create
    @wine = current_user.wines.new(wine_params)
    if @wine.save
      redirect_to wines_path, notice: "Wine was successfully created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

What do I have to do to get Devise displaying the flash messages on successful/unsuccessful login?

Comment: check this https://medium.com/@nejdetkadir/how-to-use-devise-gem-with-ruby-on-rails-7-33b89f9a9c13

Comment: Boualk, Thanks that fixed it.